# How to make directory open to certain path?

Tags: php

Example : website with directory Directory1 , inside it their is folder with index.php , so how to make Directory1 open on index.php auto?

when user type - www.Example.com/Directory1 - I want to redirect him to www.Example.com/Directory1/Folder/index.php 
I tried to check by $_GET but didn't work

Comment: Tag the name of webserver that you're using (apache, iis, etc)

Answer (score 0):

change you body tag to this body onload="redirect()"
just paste this before the ending of your body tag in your www.Example.com/Directory1

```
   <script>
   function redirect(){
  window.location.replace("www.Example.com/Directory1/Folder/index.php");
  } 
  </script>
```

Comment: You're assuming that there is a file there? Also, since it's in PHP, it would make more sense to do the redirect in PHP instead of letting the client receive unnecessary data. However, this can be fixed on the web server directly. Also, as far as we know, the OP might be building an API. Most clients that calls API's won't execute the response.

Comment: why does that matter?

Comment: and the client is receiving no data in this case he's just being redirected to another web page when the current page is loaded

Comment: It matters because there's a difference in letting the client make a request, get a response, parse the response, execute it in the browser which just redirects the call vs. the browser get's a request and returns the redirect or the correct data straight away.

Comment: anyways why dont you just post your answer instead??

Comment: Because we don't have enough info to be able to give a proper answer yet. I'm trying not to assume anything about the OP's code.

Comment: ok,the server or the client doesnt matter cz he just want the visitor to be redirected and he wil be directed both ways so...

Comment: _"ok,the server or the client doesnt matter"_ - Yes, it does. If you do a redirect in PHP or the web server, the client will just get a response header, saying where they should redirect the call. If you do it in JS, that still requires the client to contain a JS engine that can parse and execute the response. If someone uses `cURL` or something to get the contents, they won't be redirected. That's a pretty big difference.

Answer (score 0):

This example redirects the ROOT domain's URL to any subdirectory. In this example, it automatically loads example.com/subdir1:

Put this code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /subdir1/ [L]
```